# How to split string into multiple strings along certain characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new at programming so it would be help if the answers very simple, but in Javascript I have a variable called "time". It might be "10:36 P.M." for example, and I want to split it along the colon and the space, so that it becomes the three different variables: 10, 36, and P.M.

I know how to cut off the end or beginning of variables, but I need something that will save all of the parts as a separate variable.

Answer (score 6):

You can do.

```
time = time.split(/:|\s/);
```

Let me explain what's going on inside the split call.

The `/` at the start and the end means it's a regular expression. The `:` is just a colon, `\s` means a space character, the `|` between them is special in regular expressions and basically means `or`.

Comment: then `time` will be an array containing `["10", "36", "P.M."]` which you can access like `time[0]` to get the `"10"`, and I post this because the original poster seems like he wouldn't figure this out with his current knowledge.